# Apscheduler runs with Django but not running with gunnicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I am setting my scheduler using apscheduler inside a file called Scheduler.py -

```
def start_scheduler():
    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(xyz_job, trigger='cron', hour=21, minute=0)
    scheduler.start()
```

Now inside my apps.py -

```
from. Scheduler import start_scheduler
class AppNameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'appname'
    start_scheduler()
```

Then from cmd I use - `python manage.py runserver`
My scheduler works fine and everyday at 9pm, scheduler started working in background.

P.S. - This was an API with entry and end points. I tested it using postman. I was getting the output correctly.

Now on my linux server, I am doing the same thing, but instead of using django, I am using gunicorn to expose my api.

I am using the command -
`gunicorn -b server_ip:port project.wsgi --workers=2 --daemon`

Using the above gunicorn command, my api is still working fine and I am getting the output but my scheduler isn't working.

Can anyone give some insight on what can be the possible solution for this?

Comment: Unlike the very simple built-in development server gunicorn manages threads and processes. The scheduler uses its own thread and gunicorn might just end this thread or the parent thread and process. Typically scheduled jobs are run as management command via cron.

Comment: "xyz_job" mentioned in the post is a function that is replacing a pickle file that is already present there and loading this new pickle in the variable. So logically, if scheduler and gunicorn are running on different threads, it should not hinder what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, gunicorn is not running as an other process. It runs as the parent process of all processes (and threads) that execute the code (workers). Even if you spawn a thread and make it run at a given time, with two workers you will spawn two threads which most likely will run the task at the same time resulting in a race condition. That is why you never spawn extra threads in WSGI applications.

Comment: suppose i give --worker=1

Now gunicorn will execute the code (1 worker). There will be no race condition here and this thread will run the scheduler in the background and also it will serve the inputs for API.

But this is also not working.

P.S. - I get your point of this race condition because earlier I was using 4 workers and each worker was initiating this xyz_job (which actually is a model training function) and there were errors.

But can be a solution for this

Comment: I did not say it will be working with one worker, I said it will not be working with two.

Comment: haha got it. But can you suggest some solution to my query that can be done through apscheduler or gunicorn.

I tried giving `daemon=true` inside BackgroundScheduler() but it didn't work as expected.

P.S. - I don't wan't to go for cron jobs in linux, I wanted to try if something can be done at code level only.